# How to manipulate data inside html table with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, dom

Here's a HTML table:

```
<table class="myTable">
    <tr>
        <th class="myTh">Some text</th>
        <td class="myTd">18</td>
        <th>Some text</th>
        <td class="myTd">19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="myTh">>Some text</th>
        <td class="myTd">15</td>
        <th>Some text</th>
        <td class="myTd">18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="myTh">>Some text</th>
        <td class="myTd">16</td>
        <th>Some text</th>
        <td class="myTd">17</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="myTh">>Some text</th>
        <td class="myTd">20</td>
        <th>Some text</th>
        <td class="myTd">14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="myTh">>Some text</th>
        <td class="myTd">20</td>
        <th>Some text</th>
        <td class="myTd">7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="myTh">>Some text</th>
        <td class="myTd">18</td>
        <th>Some text</th>
        <td class="myTd">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="myTh">>Some text</th>
        <td class="myTd">20</td>
        <th>Some text</th>
        <td class="myTd">17</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to manipulate the numbers of the table like adding +5 to a number. For example:

```
<td class="myTd">18</td>
```

The displayed result is 18, but I would like it to be 23.

I know I should use RegEx in order to get the numbers and then do some elementary math, but I didn't find a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't need any regex, it can be done using simple regular JS or jQuery.

using Javascript:

```
function updateNumber(num){

var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("myTd");

for(var i=0;i<elems.length;i++){
 var elem = elems[i];
 elem.innerHTML = parseInt(elem.innerHTML) + num;
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but the class _myTd_ is used in other elements which content shouldn't be chankged, so regex would go for my case.